# Finding duplicate hybrid workers and delete them

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

I noticed that some of our (meaning if not all) have duplicate Hybrid workers on our servers which can lead to issues during patching (hybrid workers are doing patching in Azure).

I have now created script that gets all hybrid workers from api ($BigListOfSHRWGs) and then loops them and get more details from them which api do not provide.

```
foreach ($SHRWG in $BigListOfSHRWGs) {
    #build report string
  
    if ($SHRWG.groupType -eq "System") {
        $SHRW = Get-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker  -ResourceGroupName $RGName -AutomationAccountName $AAName -HybridRunbookWorkerGroupName $SHRWG.name
        if ($SHRW) {
            $Iteration += 1
            # Converting last seen date to string so it can be compared with current date + time (-3 hours)
            if ($SHRW.lastSeenDateTime.ToString("MMddyy HH:mm:ss") -gt $date.ToString("MMddyy HH:mm:ss")) { 
                $connectionState = "Connected"

                $ConnectedHybridWorkers = @{
                    ServerName       = $SHRW.WorkerName
                    HydridWorkerFull = $SHRW.Id.split("/")[10]
                    State            = $connectionState
                    LastSeen         = $SHRW.lastSeenDateTime
                    RegisteredDateTime = $SHRW.RegisteredDateTime

                }
                $ConnectedWorkers += $ConnectedHybridWorkers
            }
            else {
                $connectionState = "Disconnected"

                $DisconnectedHybridWorkers = @{
                    ServerName       = $SHRW.WorkerName
                    HydridWorkerFull = $SHRW.Id.split("/")[10]
                    State            = $connectionState
                    LastSeen         = $SHRW.lastSeenDateTime
                    RegisteredDateTime = $SHRW.RegisteredDateTime

                }

                $DisconnectedWorkers += $DisconnectedHybridWorkers
           
            }
  
            Write-Output "[$($Iteration)] $($SHRW.WorkerName) is: $ConnectionState. Last seen: $($SHRW.lastSeenDateTime). Registration time: $($SHRW.RegisteredDateTime)"

        
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not a bit lost what should I add as next step if I want to identify duplicate workers and delete the them so that server would be left only one worker which has been registered latest. Some of server can have up to 5 workers.

`$SHRW.WorkerName` is always FQDN of the server and `$SHRW.Id.split("/")[10]` is FQDN + unique string which is generated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> Finding duplicate hybrid workers and delete them:

*To achieve your requirement, I modified the script as below and it worked for me.*

Compare the `WorkerName` and `Id` of each worker in the `$BigListOfSHRWGs` list to identify duplicate workers.

If the `WorkerName` and `Id` are the same, the worker is a duplicate. After this, the `Remove-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker` cmdlet can be used to remove duplicate workers.

***script.ps1***:

```
$DuplicateWorkers = @()
$UniqueWorkers = @()
foreach ($SHWs in $SHW) {
    if ($SHWs.groupType -eq "System") {
        $SHRW = Get-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker  -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroup> -AutomationAccountName <automationaccount> -HybridRunbookWorkerGroupName $SHWs.name
   if ($SHWs) {
          $Worker = [PSCustomObject]@{
          WorkerName = $SHWs.WorkerName
          Id = $SHWs.Id
          LastSeen = $SHWs.lastSeenDateTime
          RegisteredDateTime = $SHWs.RegisteredDateTime
       }

  if ($UniqueWorkers.WorkerName -contains $Worker.WorkerName)        {
                $DuplicateWorkers += $Worker
        }
        else {
                $UniqueWorkers += $Worker
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach ($DuplicateWorker in $DuplicateWorkers) {
    Remove-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker -ResourceGroupName 
    <resourcegroup> -AutomationAccountName <automationaccount> -HybridRunbookWorkerGroupName $SHWs.name -HybridRunbookWorkerId $DuplicateWorker.Id
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

*Hybrid worker group got deleted in the Portal once the script ran successfully without any errors:*

[image]